# What plant is this and how can I relocate it?

Tags: identification, transplanting

Today while I was removing dandelion from my lawn I came across this plant
[image]

It seems that it naturally grew there by some miracle and I would like to relocate it and multiply it. What is the name of the plant and how can I use it and multiply it?

Comment: It looks like grass to me, why would you transplant grass?

Comment: @blackthumb, I'm pretty confident that OP means the lighter green, thick growth *between the grass blades*.

Comment: User2059078, where did the miracle growth "appear naturally", please?

Comment: Could you give some indication on where you found the plant? (region and some description of type of the place (rock, shadows,...)

Comment: On my lawn,Ontario,Canada

Answer (score 2):

I think it is some *Sedum*.

Move the plant with enough ground, and give no additional care (or similar care as the wild place).

Comment: It's a weedy sedum, think carefully whether you really want it as it might not stay where you put it.

Comment: The truth of kevinsky's statement is evidenced by the fact that this plant showed up where you didn't plant/expect it. Plants don't appear magically, it had to come from somewhere. If you really want to propagate, just take cuttings, let them dry for a day or two and plant.